# Different toc and header titles (with titlesec and titleps)

Tags: titlesec, titleps

I try to add a second optional argument to `\section` to specify different toc and header titles (like in the `memoir` class for example).

I use `titlesec` (and `titleps` via the `pagestyles` option). My code works fine **except when the section is at the very beginning of a page** (in my MWE, the fourth section shows the problem).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}
% my new \section macro
\LetLtxMacro\origsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand\section{o o m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\def\titleintoc{#1}}{\def\titleintoc{#3}}%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{\def\titleinheader{#2}}{\def\titleinheader{\titleintoc}}%
  \pretitlemark{section}{\titleinheader}%
  \origsection[\titleintoc]{#3}%
  \sectionmark{\titleinheader}%
}
% page style
\newpagestyle{section-section}[]{
  \sethead[\firsttitlemarks\sectiontitle][][]{}{}{\firsttitlemarks\sectiontitle}
  \setheadrule{.4pt}
  \setfoot*{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{section-section}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\section{section 1 everywhere}
\lipsum[10-19]
\section[section 2 in toc and in header]{section 2 in text}
\lipsum[10-20]
\section[section 3 in toc][section  3 in header]{section 3 in text}
\lipsum[10-20]
\section[section 4 in toc][section  4 in header]{section 4 in text}
\lipsum[10-19]
\end{document}
```

Top of page 8 with "section 3 in header" as expected:
[image]

Top of page of page 10 with "section 4 in toc" instead of "section 4 in header" (expected result):
[image]

How to patch `titlesec` (or `titleps`) to get the expected result?

Comment: It seems the page shipout happens between `\pretitlemark` and `\origsection`. You need to ensure somehow that both happen on the same page.

Comment: @cgnieder The page shipout occurs during `\origsection` (in the code of` `titlesec`) but I don't know which command to patch to act at the right time.

Comment: I usuallly use the `needspace` package when I need stuff to stay together. Indeed, `\needspace{2\baselineskip}` in the beginning of the new ´\section` seems to work here

Comment: @cgnieder Ok ... but the value `2\baselineskip` is empirical and may fail in other cases. I'm looking for a solution that will work in any case.

Comment: true. This is why I didn't mention it earlier…

Answer (score 1):

You could execute `\pretitlemark` a second time at the begin of ship-out of the next page using `\AtBeginShipoutNext` of the [atbegshi](https://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi) package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{xparse}
% my new \section macro
\LetLtxMacro\origsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand\section{o o m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\def\titleintoc{#1}}{\def\titleintoc{#3}}%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{\def\titleinheader{#2}}{\def\titleinheader{\titleintoc}}%
  \AtBeginShipoutNext{\pretitlemark{section}{\titleinheader}}%
  \pretitlemark{section}{\titleinheader}%
  \origsection[\titleintoc]{#3}%
  \sectionmark{\titleinheader}%
}
% page style
\newpagestyle{section-section}[]{
  \sethead[\firsttitlemarks\sectiontitle][][]{}{}{\firsttitlemarks\sectiontitle}
  \setheadrule{.4pt}
  \setfoot*{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{section-section}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum
\section{section 1 everywhere}
\lipsum[10-19]
\section[section 2 in toc and in header]{section 2 in text}
\lipsum[10-20]
\section[section 3 in toc][section  3 in header]{section 3 in text}
\lipsum[10-20]
\section[section 4 in toc][section  4 in header]{section 4 in text}
\lipsum[10-19]
\end{document}
```